# JSON objects in Swift 5

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, swift5

I'm trying to access data in a json api like below

```
"Products": [
            {
                "ProductName": "GR",
                "ShortDescription": "General service epoxy mortar system that utilizes recycled glass and rapidly renewable soy based components.",
                "PDSOverride": [
                    {
                        "FileName": "EcoLab Netherlands",
                        "FileUrl": "http://test.stonhard.com/media/2264/eco-lab-netherlands-usa-version.pdf"
                    },
                    {
                        "FileName": "General Dynamics.pdf",
                        "FileUrl": "http://test.stonhard.com/media/2060/general-dynamics.pdf"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

And I'm modeling this in a struct like this below

```
struct Solutions: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let SectionTitle: String
    let SectionImage: String
    let ProductLines: [ProductLine]
}

struct ProductLine: Codable {
    let System: String
    let Products: [Product]
}

struct Product: Codable {
    let ProductName: String
    let ShortDescription: String
    let PDSOverride: [PDSOverride]
}

struct PDSOverride: Codable {
    let FileName: String
    let FileUrl: String
}

struct SdsPdf: Codable {
    let FileName: String
    let FileUrl: String
}

struct GuideSpecPdf: Codable {
    let FileName: String
    let FileUrl: String
}
```

When I try to access the data, I get an error that says The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format. I know it's a problem with my model because when I comment out PDSOverride, SdsPdf, and GuideSpecPdf it works, but obviously I don't have access to that data. How do I model my struct so I can pull in that data?

Comment: Your posted JSON is not valid JSON. Is that the complete JSON you receive? If not, can you post a part of your complete JSON such that the JSON still remains valid?

Comment: Go to https://app.quicktype.io and plug in your JSON. It'll build a set of structs for it and you can compare those to yours to see where your problem is (or you can just use the code it generates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your JSON is only missing the closing braces, you can parse it like so:

```
struct Entry: Codable {
    let products: [Product]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case products = "Products"
    }
}

struct Product: Codable {
    let productName, shortDescription: String
    let pdsOverride: [PDSOverride]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case productName = "ProductName"
        case shortDescription = "ShortDescription"
        case pdsOverride = "PDSOverride"
    }
}

struct PDSOverride: Codable {
    let fileName: String
    let fileURL: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case fileName = "FileName"
        case fileURL = "FileUrl"
    }
}

do {
    let entries = try JSONDecoder().decode([Entry].self, from: data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for helping me out here. I'm still getting the same error but I'm guessing that it's because I didn't post my full code. I tried to only post what I needed help with but that was a bad idea. I'm going to update my question with the full code now.

Comment: The code you've added really doesn't really fit with the JSON snippet - there are lots of missing properties. As others have already suggested, take your full JSON and paste it into app.quicktype.io to get a really good starting point for your structs. Aside: initial capital letters are usually reserved for names of types in Swift, property names should start with a lowercase. Use `CodingKeys` to map between the two, like in my example.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in your model, your JSON is bad formatted as it says by the compiler your JSON needs to look like this:

```
[
    { 
        "Products": [
            {
                "ProductName": "GR",
                "ShortDescription": "General service epoxy mortar system that utilizes recycled glass and rapidly renewable soy based components.",
                "PDSOverride": [
                    {
                        "FileName": "EcoLab Netherlands",
                        "FileUrl": "http://test.stonhard.com/media/2264/eco-lab-netherlands-usa-version.pdf"
                    },
                    {
                        "FileName": "General Dynamics.pdf",
                        "FileUrl": "http://test.stonhard.com/media/2060/general-dynamics.pdf"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Also, the model could be done in this way, I recommend you to use Quicktype (https://app.quicktype.io) the online version is good and they have a desktop one:

```
// MARK: - PurpleProduct
struct PurpleProduct: Codable {
    let products: [ProductProduct]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case products = "Products"
    }
}

// MARK: - ProductProduct
struct ProductProduct: Codable {
    let productName, shortDescription: String
    let pdsOverride: [PDSOverride]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case productName = "ProductName"
        case shortDescription = "ShortDescription"
        case pdsOverride = "PDSOverride"
    }
}

// MARK: - PDSOverride
struct PDSOverride: Codable {
    let fileName: String
    let fileURL: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case fileName = "FileName"
        case fileURL = "FileUrl"
    }
}

typealias Products = [PurpleProduct]
```

And to decoded you can use the JSONDecoder, I also recommend you to check your json in this page: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com